# Regedit F3 (Find Next) not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, regedit

For some reason the F3 function key (Find Next) in Regedit has stopped working. This means I have to go to the *Edit* menu and then click *Find Next* each time, which is very time consuming.
Has anyone got a solution for getting this function back?

Comment: Try a different keyboard.

Comment: Is this a notebook? if so do other F keys work?

Comment: Does it work in other applications?

Answer (score 2):

A function key may be stuck (f-lock)?

I had the same thing on a Microsoft ergonomic board. There is no light to indicated that the F-Lock is on and it only affects Microsoft and other applications that are written to recognize it. Once on most of the F-keys will only do special ops.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that another programm / tool is absorbing the f3 hit? There could be numbers of tools that do so. Have you installed anything new lately?

Answer (score 1):

With my Microsoft Digital Pro Keyboard the <kbd>F3</kbd> key works in regedit when the <kbd>F-Lock</kbd> is ON.
This is using the DEFAULT setup in keyboard properties.

Hope this is of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Is search function disabled for other Win7 functions? - If so, this may be related:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-search-box-is-missing-in-windows-7-start-menu-explorer

Comment: It used to work, so trying another keyboard is not really the solution. No, it is a desktop PC. As far as I am aware, all F keys I use work as they should. I don´t think I have any other applications where F3 means "Find Next". The search function is enabled, although the Index service is disabled (uses too many resources and I have an alternative)